# How to bring a selected application window from a listbox to front

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, listbox, double-click

I have a windows form application. In which in a listbox, I am showing title of all the opened windows. I have done up to this. Now I want to double click on a title in the listbox.. and this will activate that window and will show upfront. My code is like this::

```
    //this function is loading all the opened windows in the listbox 

    public void LoadOpenedWindows()
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process process in processlist)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(process.MainWindowTitle);

           }
        }
        listBox1.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(ListBox1_DoubleClick);

    }
```

I tried to open the selected item by the following way.. But that is not working..

```
    private void ListBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            const uint SW_SHOW = 5;
            const int SW_RESTORE = 5;
            string selected = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            IntPtr handleOfSelected = getHandle(selected);
            ShowWindowAsync(handleOfSelected, SW_RESTORE);
            SetForegroundWindow(handleOfSelected);
            //BringWindowToTop(handleOfSelected);
            //ShowWindow(handleOfSelected, SW_SHOW);
        }
    }

    public IntPtr getHandle(string selectedItem)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(selectedItem))
            {
                hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
            }
        }
        return hWnd;
    }
```

If anyone have any idea or piece of code.. Please try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good working one..

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SOF_ProcessFront
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const UInt32 WS_MAXIMIZE = 365887488;
    const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr wHnd, int cmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadOpenedWindows();
    }

    void bringProcessToFront(int pid)
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        int style = GetWindowLong(proc.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
        ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle,
            (style & WS_MAXIMIZE) == WS_MAXIMIZE ? 3 : 9 );
        SetForegroundWindow(Process.GetProcessById(pid).MainWindowHandle);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bringProcessToFront(0);
    }

    public void LoadOpenedWindows()
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process process in processlist)
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
                listBox1.Items.Add(new ProcessAttributes()
                {
                    ProcessName = process.MainWindowTitle,
                    ProcessID = process.Id
                });
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "ProcessName";
        listBox1.DoubleClick += listBox1_DoubleClick;
    }

    void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bringProcessToFront(((ProcessAttributes)listBox1.SelectedItem).ProcessID);
    }

    class ProcessAttributes
    {
        public string ProcessName { get; set; }
        public int ProcessID { get; set; }
    }
}
}
```

The constant i've used here for WS_MAXIMIZE is working for me @ Win 8.1 64 bit
I donno whether you've to find the number for your system.

The ShowWindow function sets the WindowState of the Application. i.e we need to restore its state from minimized to normal or maximised. 2nd paramater of the ShowWindow function asks for the state to be set. i.e 3 for maximizing and 9 for restoring its state. I would like to pass 3 as parameter there if the application is not minimized and is in Maximized state. If not, then the function will try to restore a maximized window, which forces it to go from maximized to normal. You can also do like calling the showWindow function only when the window is minimized. Cauz a minimized window should be restored to show up. After that the SetForegroundWindow will bring the window to front.

Comment: I have some questions.. Can you please explain the bringProcessToFront function.. Specially the ShowWindow function..